# How to make a foreign key checking for NULL values?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table specifying types to distinguish between scalars and lists. When "scalar" exists the value is a scalar and when it is null it is a list.

```
drop table type1 cascade;
create table type1 (
  id     integer primary key,
  scalar "char",
  name   text,
  unique (id, scalar)
);
insert into type1 values
  (1, 'x', 'single'),
  (2, null, 'multi');
```

Now I have a table with values, which references the type and adds a unique constrain on the tuple (type, scalar).  This works, because NULL is distinct. If "scalar" is NULL it is possible to have more than one row per "type", because all "scalar"s are distinct.

```
drop table value1 cascade;
create table value1 (
  id     integer primary key,
  type   integer,
  scalar "char",
  value  text,
  foreign key (type, scalar) references type1 (id, scalar),
  unique (type, scalar)
);
```

It is possible to insert a single value:

```
insert into value1 values
  (11, 1, 'x', 'just one');
```

But it is not possible to add another one:

```
insert into value1 values
  (12, 1, 'x', 'another one'); -- ERROR
```

But if scalar is NULL, it is possible to have more than one:

```
insert into value1 values
  (21, 2, null, 'first'),
  (22, 2, null, 'second');
```

My problem: it is possible to reference types, which do not exist.

This works although it should not:

```
insert into value1 values
  (12, 1, null, 'another');
```

It is allowed to use (1, NULL) as a type, although in the type table are just (1, 'x') and (2, NULL).

I tried to use `match full` on the foreign key, but this seems to do something different.  It prevents also my intended use of multiple null values, because it rejects multiple null values at all.

I want to allow multiple NULLs in `value1.scalar` if `type1.scalar` is NULL. But I want to reject any NULL in `value1.scalar` if `type1.scalar` is not NULL. How can I express this?

Comment: `unique (type, scalar)` on the `value1` table is wrong, it needs a `WHERE` to filter only to scalars. `MATCH PARTIAL` is what you want, but not implemented yet. Maybe use a flag value to signal a list?

Comment: From my understanding, you’re using a Sum Type. I suggest reading https://typeable.io/blog/2019-11-21-sql-sum-types for other options. What you’re doing seems too complicated to me.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes this was way too spooky. I now use a range and a before insert trigger. It is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

- The `unique` constraint on `value1` is enforcing a single row per set of `(type, scalar)`, but you want non-scalars to allow multiples. Unique constraints do not allow filters.
  You can use a filtered unique index `where (scalar is not null)` instead, however.....
- ... the other issue is that both `MATCH SIMPLE` and `MATCH FULL` don't do what you want. You need `MATCH PARTIAL`, but this has not been implemented yet.

Instead, use flag value such as `\x0` (the NUL character) to signal a non-scalar, and make the `scalar` column non-nullable on `type1`.

```
create table type1 (
  id     integer primary key,
  scalar "char" not null,
  name   text,
  unique (id, scalar)
);

create table value1 (
  id     integer primary key,
  type   integer,
  scalar "char",
  value  text,
  foreign key (type, scalar) references type1 (id, scalar) match full  -- or match simple (the default) if you prefer
);

create unique index ux on value1 (type, scalar) where (scalar <> '\x0');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/p1rtsBNw)